# how to make in lisp a reader macro to read raw strings (ie backslash is a literal not an escape character)

Tags: macros, common-lisp, reader

In python you can write this r"c:\data"

How do I the same in lisp? ie I want a reader macro that has the same functionality so I no longer need to escape backslashes in windows paths. I do not want to use forward slashes as plenty of commands in windows dont understand them.

Comment: Actually, `#"` isn't in use yet, so you could use `#"c:\data"`

Comment: Example libraries defining reader macro for strings: [pythonic-string-reader](https://github.com/smithzvk/pythonic-string-reader), [cl-heredoc](https://github.com/outergod/cl-heredoc), [mstrings](https://git.sr.ht/~shunter/mstrings).

Answer (score 2):

For instance

```
(defun read-literal-string (stream delimiter arg)
  (declare (ignore arg))
  (loop for char = (read-char stream nil stream)
        when (eq char stream)
          do (error "hit end of stream")
        until (char= char delimiter)
        collect char into chars
        finally (return (coerce chars 'string))))

(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\" #'read-literal-string)
```

And now

```
> #"fo\o"
"fo\\o"

> #"foo\"
"foo\\"
```

obviously a real version would be more carefully written